# height of text starting in table not equal

Tags: tabularx, height

I have a question about my table. I don't have the text starting from the same line-height between the top rule and the bottom rule. Could you help me how I could adjust that the height between the top rule and the line as well as the text line and the bottom rule is equal?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength\colwidth
\usepackage{float}  


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Amount of substance calculated for capsule preparation. 42 capsules per batch.}
\settowidth\colwidth{GGG} % set width of 1st col.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}P{\colwidth}*{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule 
Sample &   Labelled substance  [$\si{\milli\mol\per\milli\liter}$]  &jj & jj & jk & kj & jj\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\endtabularx
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the definition of your `P` type column to `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}` or, if you need this `P` columntype elsewhere in your document, define a new column type with this definition.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but there is no need for a set of `$` around the `\si` command.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `P` type column you use in your table is defined as a left aligned `m` type column, which itself vertically centers contens (baseline is in the center). If you don't want vertically centered but top aligned contents, change the definition to use a `p` type column instead of `m`:

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```